# how to read a text file before being created by another function in python

Tags: python, function, text, readfile

In my python code, I call a function written in FreeFem++ and then I save the output from FreeFem++ code in a text file and I want to read this in python.

```
def f(x):
    os.system("Here the FreeFem++ code will be called and the result will be saved as out.txt")
    myfile=open("out.txt")
    return myfile.read()
```

The problem is that, when I run the python code, as the out.txt has not been created, it gives me an error saying the out.txt doesn't exist!

Comment: `os.system` is rather crude. [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) gives you _far_ more control, although it does have a bit of a learning curve.

Comment: Are you sure that the file is saved in the same folder as your script?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Actually my text file is in the following format(when it is without my parameters, it works fine!)

Comment: @jonrsharpe                                                                          myfile = open("Data_"+str(x[0,0]/3600)+"_"+str(x[0,1])+"_"+str(x[0,2])+".txt")                   I have saved the txt file with same format in FreeFem++

Answer (score 4):

Use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) to call your freefem++ program, and make sure that your call actually generates the file before it exists. You could check that by adding a breakpoint just before the `open`.

So change to subprocess:

```
def f(x):
    cp = subprocess.run(['freefem++', '--argument', '--other_argument'])
    if cp.returncode != 0:
        print('Oops… failure running freefem++!')
        sys.exit(cp.returncode) # actually you should be raising an exception as you're in a function
    if not os.path.exists('out.txt'):
        print('Oops… freefem++ failed to create the file!')
        sys.exit(1) # same you'd better be raising an exception as you're in a function
    with open('out.txt', 'r') as ff_out:
        return ff_out # it is better to return the file object so you can iterate over it
```

To check that your file is indeed created before opening it:

```
def f(x):
    cp = subprocess.run(['freefem++', '--argument', '--other_argument'])
    if cp.returncode != 0:
        print('Oops… failure running freefem++!')
        sys.exit(cp.returncode)

    # XXX Here we make a breakpoint, when it's stopping open a shell and check for the file!
    # if you do not find the file at this point, then your freefem++ call is buggy and your issue is not in the python code, but in the freefem++ code.
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

    with open('out.txt', 'r') as ff_out:
        return ff_out # it is better to return the file object so you can iterate over it
```

Finally, the most elegant solution would be for you to make that the freefem++ program outputs everything to stdout, and that you take that output through a pipe within python, using [`subprocess.popen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects):

```
def f(x):
    p = subprocess.popen(['freefem++'…], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, _ = p.communicate()
    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception('Oops, freefem++ failed!')
    return out
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, with my previous method of calling, it works fine when I save the txt file with a simple name.txt   the problem is that I use the string of my variables to save my file and that causes the error.    I want to read my txt file in this format:                                                                                                myfile=open("Data_"+str(x[0,0]/3600)+"_"+str(x[0,1])+"_"+str(x[0,2])+".txt")

Comment: Well, use format strings to better control the filename generation (`data_{}{}{}.txt".format(x,y,z)`) also set it up as a variable so you can print it before using it to make sure you do it right, and even check for the file existence using `os.path.exists`. Oh and also use context managers to open a file (`with open(...) as f`) to avoid leaking file descriptors.

Comment: And use `subprocess` and not `os.system()`, as it is considered deprecated in modern python.